# Why plot features?

Tags: feature-extraction, plotting

In PyTorch's tutorial, [Speech Recognition With Wav2Vec2](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/speech_recognition_pipeline_tutorial.html), the acoustic features are extracted from the audio waveform (even though it was unnecessary, as the model can perform feature extraction and classification with one step), and then plotted.
[image: Screenshot from PyTorch tutorial]

What do we gain from such plots? Do they tell us anything about the model's weights?

Answer (score 0):

I think we are plotting the progress of feature extraction per epoch. So obviously we can get an idea about the weight change, backpropagation and many more. because in the end each layer will be returning tensor

Comment: Well, in the tutorial I linked, they only plot the features once per transformer layer (the model is pre-trained). Meaning it can't imply change - so what can we learn from the plots?